# Java Compare Numbers error

Tags: java, arrays, generics, compare

I have the following code which finds wheather an object is in array like if number `2` is in `numbers` array, if yes return `true` else return `false`.

Code:

```
static <T extends Comparable,V extends T> boolean isIn(T t,V[] v){
    for(T tt : v){
        if(t.equals(v)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Caller Code:

```
if(isIn(n,numao)) {
    System.out.println("The number is in the list");
} else {
    System.out.println("No!");
}
```

`numao` creation:

```
int savg = (int) cin("Enter Starting point of average number");
int eavg = (int) cin("Enter ending point");
int ttl =0;
for(int i=savg;i<eavg;i++) {
    ttl++;
}
ttl++;
Integer numao[] = new Integer[ttl];
System.out.println(numao.length);
for(int i=0;;i++) {
    if(savg >eavg) {
        break;
    } else {
        numao[i] = savg++;
    }
}
```

Everytime it returns `No!`, I don't understand why.

Easter Egg :) ->

```
<img src="person.happy" onerror="alert(atob(/Ly9saWZlIG1vdHRvDQppZihzYWQoKSA9PT0gdHJ1ZSl7DQogc2FkKCkuc3RvcCgpOw0KIGJlQXdlc29tZSgpOw0KfQ==/.source))" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if(t.equals(v)){` be `if(t.compareTo(v) == 0){` in order to maintain the contract between the values and `Comparable`?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer I got the solution, see below

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Those are strongly recommended to be the same according to the contract of `Comparable`.

Comment: @newacct While that is correct, there is no requirement for it to be that way (it's only a suggestion), as context may require a different implementation, when using Comparable, it would be better to use the functionality of the interface to be sure you are getting the result you expect

Comment: @MadProgrammer: From the question it seems the OP doesn't ever need an ordering (which is what `Comparable` is for), and most likely the OP incorrectly thought that `Comparable` is needed to test for equality. So the most appropriate suggestion in my opinion would be to remove `extends Comparable`.

Comment: @newacct Agreed (removing `Comparable`) as it just confuses the issue

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out on my own!

The line in code block '1'

`if(t.equals(v)){`
must be `if(t.equals(tt)){`

becasue its the variable `tt` which is looping not `v`.